# Jquery counter that need to reset itself

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

Hello I have added code in here:

[jfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/3/)

I need the timer to restart itself when it hits time 0, so that it starts again in with 24 hours- countdown.

can you help me with the proper code for? that setting?

Right now, when it hit time 0, it starts with -1, -2 etc.

here is the code:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>

function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "You now have "+hrs+' hours '+mins+' minuts '+secs+' seconds' +" To ensure delivery within 24 hours";
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

var countdown;
function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);

}

setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Thank you

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the counter is only getting negative, between 1900 and 0000 - so it would be sufficient to create an if statement for the hrs variable. inside this statement, you decide wether to substract now from 18(or whatever your closing deadline would be) or from 18 + 24:

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  if (now.getHours() > 18){
    var hrs =18-now.getHours() +24;
  }else{
    var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
  }

 var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
 var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();

  timeLeft = "You now have "+hrs+' hours '+mins+' minuts '+secs+' seconds' +" To ensure delivery within 24 hours";
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}
```

updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/4/

Comment: thank you for your reply. 
What I am searching for is a counter, that reset itself back to24hours and counting 23:59, 23:58 etc... So basically it should count from 12 - to 12 constantly.

Comment: thats what it does. you can try it, by changing the 18 to anything lower than the actual time. in my case, it would be 11

Comment: don't forget to approve the solution ;)

Comment: I did - Ive added the code with the correct time in here
http://jsfiddle.net/srwpyac0/23/ and added the danish text.

There has come up some new features it needs to support. In the weekends (saturday and sunday) it should count to monday 11.00. And what about holy days? hmm

Comment: this would be a new question ... and you would need at least an off-day list - better a calendar plugin - to get all days off and add 24hours per day off in line...